# Не показывает версию python

Tags: python

Не могу посмотреть версию питона. Уже переустанавливал питон, не помогло. Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Команда `where python` что показывает?

Comment: Попробуйте так `py --version` или `py -V`

Comment: py -V сработало, спасибо большое

Comment: странно почему не работает python, но проблема решена

Comment: Так и какая версия? Может это что-нибудь объяснило бы )

Comment: @CrazyElf очень частая проблема у начинающих, поскольку `python launcher` для винды запускается командой `py`, а не `python`. Можно предположить, поскольку не было описания, что ничего не кастомизировалось, поэтому работают из коробки.

Comment: @Dmitry, какая-то ерунда. У меня всегда работало через python. Я до этого видел подобные вопросы, что у кого-то команда python при запуске просто Python выводит, но никогда воспроизвести не мог.

Comment: @insolor [в доке](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) упоминается только `py`

Comment: @Dmitry этот раздел конкретно по лаунчеру py, он и описывает использование этого лаунчера. При этом технически ничего не должно мешать использовать команду python.

Comment: @insolor возможно надо покапаться ещё, но данный, если так можно назвать, баг встречается более, чем очень часто

Comment: @insolor [может здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896577/10562663) найдете ответ в различии

Comment: @Dmitry мне не нужен ответ о различии) Я и так знаю различие py и python, и у меня все работает через python

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `python --version`..

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134891/discussion-on-answer-by-wanna-feel----python).

Answer (score 0):

в итоге, если писать python, то ничего не измениться, помогло использование py вместо python.